# How to achieve the following file structure when archiving a directory in PHP using ZipArchive();

Tags: php, zip, archive, directory-structure, php-ziparchive

I'm writing a PHP script that archives a selected directory and all its sub-folders. The code works fine, however, I'm running into a small problem with the structure of my archived file.

Imagine the script is located in **var/app/current/example/two/** and that it wants to backup everything plus its sub directories starting at **var/app/current**

When I run the script it creates an archive with the following structure:

```
/var/app/current/index.html
/var/app/current/assets/test.css
/var/app/current/example/file.php
/var/app/current/example/two/script.php
```

Now I was wondering how:

**a)** How can I remove the /var/app/current/ folders so that the root directory of the archive starts beyond the folder current, creating the following structure:

```
index.html
assets/test.css
example/file.php
example/two/script.php
```

**b)** Why & how can I get rid of the "/" before the folder var?

```
//Create ZIP file
$zip = new ZipArchive();  
$tmpzip = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/".substr(md5(TIME_NOW), 0, 10).random_str(54).".zip";

//If ZIP failed
if($zip->open($tmpzip,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!== TRUE)
{
    $status = "0";
}
else
{
    //Fetch all files from directory    
    $basepath = getcwd(); //   var/app/current/example/two
    $basepath = str_replace("/example/two", "", $basepath); //   var/app/current
    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($basepath);

    //Loop through each file
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $files => $file)
    {
        if(($file->getBasename() !== ".") && ($file->getBasename() !== ".."))
        {
            $zip->addFile(realpath($file), $file);  
        }
    }

    $zip->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with:

```
$zip->addFile(realpath($file), str_replace("/var/app/current/","",$file));
```

Comment: Wouldn't be a solution as /var/app/current/ is a variable. The script should work with any directory structure.

Comment: Well, your question was `How can I remove the /var/app/current/ folders so that the root directory of the archive starts beyond the folder current, creating the following structure...` and this does answer your question. If you need different answer then you should provide more details. Can you use variable instead of `"/var/app/current/"` in `str_replace` that I provided? For example:  `$zip->addFile(str_replace($root,"",realpath($file)), $file); ` where `$root="/var/app/current/";`?

Comment: The entire approach wouldn't work. You cannot use a str_replace in a addFile function. I appreciate your help through (:

Comment: Yes you can I just used it in wrong place. Second parameter of addFile() is actually the name you want to appear in the zip archive (localname -
If supplied, this is the local name inside the ZIP archive that will override the filename). I just could not remember of the top of my head if it is the first or the second argument. Read more at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Comment: Cheers! I should have looked better. Thanks a lot & have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the ZipArchive class before but with most archiver application it works if you change the directory and use relative path.
So you can try to use `chdir` to the folder you want to zip up.

Comment: Don't see how that would work.

'chdir("../../../");
$test = getcwd();
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($test);'

$test outputs /var/app/current/mybb

Comment: With being in the directory you want to zip up you should not call getwd just set $ test to '.' - the actual directory